# Python multiprocess - indexing multiple returns

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, multiprocessing

I'm trying to return multi-dimensional arrays as well as a few meta-parameters using Python's multiprocessing pool functionality.

However when I try to index the multi-dimensional arrays and check their sizes, I get sizes of (N,) rather than what I expect which is (10,5,3,3) in the following example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

def function(x):
        cube = np.ones((5,3,3))
        a,b,c = 1,2,3
        return cube,a,b,c

pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)

results = list(tqdm(pool.imap(function,range(10)),total=10))
results = [x for x in results if str(x) != 'nan']
results = np.array(results)
```

I would index results, to try and recover all the generated `cube`s, using the following:

```
results[:,0].shape
```

and in this example I get the result:

```
(10,)
```

I feel like this is a rather basic problem but is there a way to set up this multiprocessing code in a way that indexing `results` yields the multidimensional shape I expected to see?

Edit: It is necessary in this example to return a,b, and c as well as it is this is a simple example of a larger piece of code where I require the return of a cube and multiple parameters.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I expect which is `(10,5,3,3)` in the following example

To get the shape of the final array you don't need to *drag* those variables `a,b,c` as a result of the target function, just return `cube` (which is multidimensional numpy array). Actually, they don't seem meaningful in that context.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

def function(x):
        cube = np.ones((5,3,3))
        # a,b,c = 1,2,3
        return cube

pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)

results = list(tqdm(pool.imap(function,range(10)),total=10))
results = [x for x in results if str(x) != 'nan']
results = np.array(results)
print(results.shape)
```

The output:

```
100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:00<00:00, 15845.50it/s]
(10, 5, 3, 3)
```

---

In case if multiple variables need to be returned - just extract all the *cubes* from result:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

def function(x):
        cube = np.ones((5,3,3))
        a,b,c = 1,2,3
        return cube, a, b, c

pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)

results = list(tqdm(pool.imap(function,range(10)),total=10))
results = [x for x in results if str(x) != 'nan']
cubes = np.array([r[0] for r in results])
print(results[0])  # print 1st result item
print(cubes.shape)
```

The output:

```
100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:00<00:00, 51590.46it/s]
(array([[[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]]), 1, 2, 3)
(10, 5, 3, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately my example is a simpler version of a piece of code I actually wish to run but encounters the same problem. In that code I do require outputting a cube and multiple variables so unfortunately I can't remove them here. I have added an edit note into the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @user8188120, I don't problem there - see my update

Answer (score 0):

When I run this piece of code, I get a `(10,4)` numpy array returned, which correspondes to `(ntrials, len(outputTuple)`. So the `return cube, a, b, c` gets packed as a tuple, and then that gets placed in the `results` array. So if you want to access your values:

```
cube = results[:,0] # returns a (10, 5, 3, 3) as you want
a = results[:,1] # (10,) array with the a values
b = results[:,2] # (10,) array
c = results[:,3] # (10,) array
```

Or if you wanted all the auxiliary parameters together:

```
abc = results[:,1:] # (10, 3) array. Aux parameters separated by trial
```

Comment: Hmm that's really strange, I get (10,) for the cube shape after indexing.. do you think this is as a result of different Python versions? I'm on Python 3.7.

Comment: That is very strange indeed. I'm using Python 3.7.4 on Fedora 29. I tried with 2.7.16 as well and got the same `(10,4)` shape of the output.